# matlab - can I view functions run by plugins?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plugins, eeglab

I am using matlab R2012b, with the eeglab plugin. This is a plugin with a GUI, while this is very helpful I want to be able to see what functions the plugin is running when I use the GUI is this possible?

Comment: the solution, for eeglab at least, is to run: `eegh` this provides the recent history for the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the command EEG.history into the command window after your session with EEGLAB it will print out a list of the commands called for the session.

example ...

> > EEG.history

ans =

EEG = pop_fileio('D:\work\Matlab libraries\training_course_materials\Eeglab_data.set');
EEG.setname='temp_file';
EEG = eeg_checkset( EEG );

> > 

If you then select a function of interest, e.g. highlight pop_fileio above and then right click you can select 'Open selection' option from the popup menu and the file pop_fileio.m' will open in a new tab in the MATLAB editor for you to look at it.

It's worth noting that when you run EEGLAB as a GUI that a lot of subsequent function calls are made with default parameter setting however if you call them directly from your own code you can then change these default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the execution of a program using debugger. It is [very easy](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182) using matlab's editor.  Alternatively you can use [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) to see what was exectured and how many times.

Answer (score 0):

When you select an option on the GUI, a new form/window will open. The name of the fucntion will be displayed at the top of this new window. Locate where you have stored EEG lab and find the function pertaining to the name and you can view the details in your editor window.